# EditText in Android not working/allowing to enter value

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

My EditText element is displaying well in popup window but its not allowing to enter values,I cant type anything inside that edittext element. 
here i have attached xml code and screenshot.if you want my main activity class java code too let me know i can add it here.

[image: here the screenshot of UI]
xml code :

```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/texttitle1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textColor="#891800"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Create Appoinment" />

                <TimePicker
                    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:timePickerMode="spinner" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Easy"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="openNewActivity"
                    android:text="Save" />



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dismiss"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Back to Menu" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: you need to pass some height to Edit Text

Comment: gave height too but same nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution:

1.In Manifest file please write windowSoftInputMode :

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

2. Please put these lines in main LinearLayout

   ```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   ```

3.Please check the document

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: still same :/ i added it

Comment: May i know keyboard is raising or not, when you focus the editext?

Comment: not raising out i even i added this too
android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: where you added?

Comment: to edittext 

 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Easy"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:focusable ="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                />

Comment: Not here for Linearlayout you have to give <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"        android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">

Answer (score 0):

take the input type text noSuggestions and replace it with text

Comment: done but still same its not allowing to type anything there even its not showing keyboard

Comment: ok put focusable true and focusable in touch mode true to edittext

Comment: first put the toast message on the edittext clcik listener and check whether it is detecting the click events and then we start to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Try with below XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texttitle1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Create Appoinment"
            android:textColor="#891800"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Easy"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="openNewActivity"
            android:text="Save" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dismiss"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back to Menu" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had accidentally put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the parent layout,which blocks widgets inside this layout focusing. That is why, it was not working :)

If you have this line, please remove and it will work just fine